# Why does my YouTube code not work with all playlists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

[jsfiddle playlist first](http://jsfiddle.net/kollukrishna_001/90175qqg/)

Alum Songs Playlist perfectly works but unfortunately the same code is not working for another playlist Id

[jsfiddle playlist second](http://jsfiddle.net/kollukrishna_001/cqp20zLc)

Medical Animated Playlist does not work

```js
var playListURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/B2A4E1367126848D?v=2&alt=json&callback=?';
var videoURL = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
$.getJSON(playListURL, function(data) {
  var list_data = "";
  $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
    var feedTitle = item.title.$t;
    var feedURL = item.link[1].href;
    var fragments = feedURL.split("/");
    var videoID = fragments[fragments.length - 2];
    var vid = item.media$group.yt$videoid.$t;
    var url = videoURL + videoID;
    var vidtitle = item.title.$t;
    var vidviews = item.yt$statistics.viewCount;
    var content = item.media$group.media$description.$t;
    var thumb = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoID + "/default.jpg";
    list_data += '<a href=' + url + '><table width="100%"><tbody><tr><td width="110"><img height="150" width="150" alt=' + feedTitle + ' src=' + thumb + ' style="padding: 5px;"></td><td><h5><a name="p4">' + vidtitle + '</a></h5><p><b>Views:-</b> <b>' + vidviews + '</b> </p><section class="toggle active"><label>Case Study <i class="icon icon-youtube-play"></i></label><div class="toggle-content"><p>' + content + '</p></p></div></section></td></tr></tbody></table></a><hr/>';

  });
  $(list_data).appendTo(".cont");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="cont">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the video has no views, and as a result `item.yt$statistics` is undefined for some of the videos. Remove those variables, or check for undefined values before accessing `viewCount`.

I also noticed that the provided jsFiddle was not including jQuery, so I updated that in the jsFiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/cqp20zLc/1/